# Scrapy CrawlSpider not following links

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am trying to crawl some attributes from all(#123) detail pages given on this category page - http://stinkybklyn.com/shop/cheese/ but scrapy is not able to follow link pattern I set, I checked on scrapy documentation and some tutorials as well but No Luck!

Below is the code:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

class Stinkybklyn(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Stinkybklyn"
    allowed_domains = ["stinkybklyn.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stinkybklyn.com/shop/cheese/chandoka",
    ]
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\/shop\/cheese\/.*'),
         callback='parse_items', follow=True)


    def parse_items(self, response):
        print "response", response
        hxs= HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        title=hxs.select("//*[@id='content']/div/h4").extract()
        title="".join(title)
        title=title.strip().replace("\n","").lstrip()
        print "title is:",title
```

Can someone please advise what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem with your code is that **you have not set the [`rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules) for the `CrawlSpider`**.

Other improvements I would suggest:

- there is no need to instantiate `HtmlXPathSelector`, you can use `response` directly
- `select()` is deprecated now, use `xpath()`
- get the `text()` of the `title` element in order to retrieve, for instance, get `Chandoka` instead of `<h4>Chandoka</h4>`
- I think you meant to start with the cheese shop catalog page instead: http://stinkybklyn.com/shop/cheese

The complete code with the applied improvements:

```
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class Stinkybklyn(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Stinkybklyn"
    allowed_domains = ["stinkybklyn.com"]

    start_urls = [
        "http://stinkybklyn.com/shop/cheese",
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r'\/shop\/cheese\/.*'), callback='parse_items', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_items(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div/h4/text()").extract()
        title = "".join(title)
        title = title.strip().replace("\n", "").lstrip()
        print "title is:", title
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some syntax errors. 
Try this,

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector


class Stinkybklyn(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Stinkybklyn"
    allowed_domains = ["stinkybklyn.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://stinkybklyn.com/shop/cheese/",
    ]

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'/shop/cheese/')), callback='parse_items'),

        )

    def parse_items(self, response):
    print "response", response
```